# from token transaction detail, how can I know if token is actually transferred?

Tags: transactions, tokens, contract-invocation

I am implementing support of multiple tokens in my application.
I want to listen new token received transactions.

I got that I need to decode the **input** data in any transaction to get the **toAddress** and **Amount** of token transferred.
But I am confused at a point how can I know if token is really transferred or not? because **method** in **input** data can be different for different contracts.

So I know that **transfer**, **transferFrom** are methods used to transfer the token. so I can confirm if token-transfer is happened.
But I found **Transfer** and **Sweep** two methods for a contract. (for eg. [Omisego Contract](https://etherscan.io/token/0xd26114cd6EE289AccF82350c8d8487fedB8A0C07#writeContract), [Omisego Transaction-1](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x370ddbc0d10edb389534068115617b2a5377b0adbbb1d204d4defb4f949a965d), [Omisego Transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x4fb6ede96fb874d6087eeafed11107f519521e0082baba8f11262c984ad9f686)). but then I found **depositToken** method for another contract(for eg. [Sharder Contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x2a0c0dbecc7e4d658f48e01e3fa353f44050c208#writeContract) [Sharder Transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xe2a18a18180d960061611c27ced38b965b445a6263a54b1495abf27b9ce1d628)).

So my questions.

1. How can I get a list of transfer-methods for different tokens?(for eg. **transfer**-**transferFrom** for **Omisego**, **depositToken** for **Sharder** etc..)
2. is **Mint** method too a type of token transfer method, its here [Omisego Contract](https://etherscan.io/token/0xd26114cd6EE289AccF82350c8d8487fedB8A0C07#writeContract)?
3. or may be, if transaction is on Etherscan, assume tokens/ETH are always transferred from one address to another address/contract.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what standards are meant for. Without a standard it's next to impossible to know what functions are supposed to do what and which tokens support which functionality.

The best-known token stardard is ERC20 which defines the function names and some other stuff. If a token does not follow that standard it isn't a valid ERC20 token.

You can't really *assume* anything with contracts which are not ERC20 compliant. They may do whatever they wish with whatever functions.

Strictly speaking, nobody guarantees that a ERC20 contract transfers tokens with a `transfer` function either as the implementation is not built-in, so you still have to make other checks to make sure (check token balances before and after).

Comment: Thanks Lauri for the information. My need was to check while transaction happens, so I managed by listening on `Transfer` event realtime for respective erc20 tokens. I hope transfer event will be triggered only when transfer is happened for ERC20 token

Comment: In typical implementations yes, it is called only when the transfer has been succesful. But there is no absolute guarantee - it depends on the implementation.

Comment: Got it Lauri, Thanks. I will assume most of the successful and big ERC20 tokens follows this. no other option ;-)